# Equally spacing PHP generated divs (Not using flex)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a image box which i want to randomly display images stored in my images file using **PHP**, this portion works fine, my issue is that i need to make the images equally spaced to fill the width of the site.

This is what it currently looks like :

[image]

I have put a red line to the right, this is where i need the `div` to reach.

I have tried using a flex method to do this however it just squeezes all divs when the page is shrunk, this i dont like as i plan to be making the site responsive.

Currently i have started to implement the span stretch way of doing it, however this doesnt seem to work.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tile_wrapper">
    <?php
        $res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM randomimg ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 16");
        while($row=$res->fetch_array())
        {
            include 'includes/tile.php'; 
        } 
    ?>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<div id="tile_image_wrapper">
    <a href="storepage.php?name=<?php echo $row['storename']; ?>" />
        <?php 
            echo 
                '<div id="tile_inner_wrapper">' .
                    '<img src="images/stores/' . $row['storename'] . '.png">' .
                '</div>';
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tile_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
     text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}


#tile_image_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width:130px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:3px;
}

#tile_inner_wrapper {
    height:50px;
    width:130px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}

#tile_wrapper img {
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:40px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#tile_image_wrapper:hover {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you're not using Flex, why did you tag the question with it?  Also, please note that the Flex tag refers to Apache Flex, not to CSS.

Comment: Because it was a suggested tag. I appologise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error when creating the DOM from your PHP files since you close the a tag around your image tiles immediately and try to close it once more after defining the tile. Try to change

```
<a href="storepage.php?name=<?php echo $row['storename']; ?>" />
```

to

```
<a href="storepage.php?name=<?php echo $row['storename']; ?>">
```

I've made a jsfiddle show this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/3qp6fgwz/1/

You have also a couple typos in your css (`*display:inline` and a missing semicolon in `.stretch`).

Also note that the CSS3 property text-justify is currently only supported in Internet Explorer 5.5+ (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, your answer is perfect and has solved my problem. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

tile_wrapper id should be on

```
text-align:center;
```

property.

Comment: This does make the images central, but not equally spaced stretching the entire width of the sites inner wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
margin:0 auto;
width:960px; //or what you desire
```

in tile_wrapper id

Comment: This does make the images central, but not equally spaced stretching the entire width of the sites inner wrapper

Comment: then you should modify the margin, padding and width of the inner blocks

Answer (score 0):

I would make divs display-inline with text-center to center images inside, while making parent div be centered. That way you would get something quite similar to what you want and probably satisfactory.

But, if you want to dynamically change their widths to always fully fill space on any window resize, you would need JavaScript to tell you how wide is your area and to resize every div (or maybe to calculate where to insert break while widths are defined in percentages using media queries? - just a though..)